# How to save transcript to a text file in Mozilla DeepSpeech?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, mozilla-deepspeech

This command is working and display the output

However I could not find the command to save the output a text file

What are my options? I want to generate text of speech to upload youtube video for subtitling (yes youtube algorithm failed to auto generate)

```
deepspeech --model deepspeech-0.8.2-models.pbmm --scorer deepspeech-0.8.2-models.scorer --audio audio/a.wav
```

Here the above command output but I can not save output to a file which I need

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add

```
> output.txt
```

In your case:

```
deepspeech --model deepspeech-0.8.2-models.pbmm --scorer deepspeech-0.8.2-models.scorer --audio audio/a.wav > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the JSON output of the native client? Add

```
--json
```

to your call. For more options check the [argument list](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/blob/b72e2643c497d4c9c16274753fa9b51bfa90f638/native_client/python/client.py#L90).

Comment: The `--json` flag doesn't actually take a parameter for an output file. It just outputs a json structure to the terminal the same way the command without the `--json` flag outputs the transcribed text to the terminal